# How can I force specific jar with version from in my `gradle.build`?

Tags: java, gradle, jar, build, build.gradle

I have tried to exclude some jar from my build like that

```
configurations.runtime.exclude (group:'com.google.guava' , module: 'guava', version: '22.0')
```

and got an error that version is not a recognized filed.

How can I force specific jar with version from in my `gradle.build`?

I know I can remove without version, but i do want to use same jar with lower version.

That jar is not pulled directly, but via other dependent jar

Answer (score 0):

You [can't provide a version](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/artifacts/ExcludeRule.html) when you exclude a dependency.

Just do like this :

```
configurations.runtime.exclude group:'com.google.guava', module: 'guava'
```

edit, try this according to your comment :

```
configurations.runtime {
    resolutionStrategy {
        force 'com.google.guava:guava:your.lower.version'
    }
}
```

Comment: I know I can remove without version, but i do want to use same jar with lower version.

That jar is not pulled directly, but via other dependent jar